# Make a python class method callable using 2 names

Tags: python, class

There is an existing class which I'd like some of it's functions to be callable using a different name so it complies with a new interface.

It seems I can achieve this using one of these 2 ways:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fun2 = getattr(self, "fun1")

    def fun1(self):
        print("Hello from func1")
```

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fun1(self):
        print("Hello from func1")

    fun2 = fun1
```

I myself prefer option 1.

Is there one way generally preferred over the other? Or a third way I haven't though about maybe?

Comment: wouldn't `self.fun2 = self.fun1` also work?

Comment: The first solution causes a reference cycle, so it's bad. (Yes, yes, I know python has a cycle detector... but have you ever *had* reference cycles in your programs? Trust me, you wanna avoid them.)

Comment: In the first case, your instance has a function as an attribute The second simply aliases the method on the class. You should use the second

Comment: also note that your second example is setting the alias in the class namespaces whereas the first example is setting in the instance space which can have other consequences

Comment: @VinceW. it will work. The other option is to override `__getattr__`. There preferred - I don't think there is clear answer to that. The question is why you need that, sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @khachik I think it is pretty clear that the second is preferred, the first has no advantages as far as I can see.